# $B^A \subseteq P(A\times B)$ and $A\times B\subseteq P(P(A\cup B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Q1 - Let G be the set of all functions from A to B. Show that
>
> a)$$ G\subseteq P(A\times B),$$
> b)$$ A\times B\subseteq P(P(A\cup B)).$$

By P I mean the power set.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145547/the-collection-of-continuous-functions-between-any-2-compact-hausdorff-spaces-fo/145550#145550) may be of some help.

Answer (score 3):

a) A *function* $f: A \to B$ is a special kind of *relation from $A$ to $B$*, which is nothing more than a subset of $A \times B$. That is, $f \in P(A\times B)$.

Since $G$ consists only of functions, it follows by definition of $\subseteq$ that $G \subseteq P(A \times B)$.

---

b) The Cartesian product $A \times B$ is defined as:

$$A \times B = \{(a,b): a \in A, b \in B\}$$

where $(a,b)$ is an *ordered pair*. In the definition of ordered pair that you've been given (attributed to Kuratowski), we have $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Now, $\{a\} \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $\{a,b\}\subseteq A \cup B$; therefore, $(a,b) \subseteq P(A \cup B)$. That is to say, $A \times B$ is a collection of elements of $P(P(A\cup B))$, i.e.:

$$A \times B \subseteq P(P(A\cup B))$$